# Unwanted Padding in QTextEdit HTML Subset <img>

Tags: html, image, html-table, pyqt, padding

I am trying to insert an image in a table html inside a QTextEdit Subset.
I would like that image to fit perfectly with the table width.
Unfortunately nothing goes smooth with Qt and an annoying padding is left at the right and under the image.

Here is the simplified code (use any image to test), anyone as any idea on how to avoid it?

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, Qt

class Labhtml(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        html= '''
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="bar.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        '''

        self.setText(html)


class Example(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        layout.addWidget(Labhtml())

        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Qt is full of these glitches when it comes to subset I am nearly going to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the whitespace you've added within the `td` tag. So one way to fix the problem is like this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><img src="image.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, use fixed dimensions that are smaller than the image:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td width="0" height="0">
        <img src="image.png">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @user3755529. Don't take it too hard :) Qt's simplified html has it's limitations, so it takes some getting used to. You will probably find you need to juggle things around a bit sometimes to get what you want. The upside is that it is *way* faster than a full-blown html browser.